# Correct type definition for a React class with static member components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, typescript-typings

I've published a React component on npm (written in JS) and would like to provide a .d.ts typings file for it. However I'm stuggling to make the types work out. Here's the (simplified) situation (in JS):

```
class Async extends React.Component { ... }
const Pending = (props) => <div>{props.children}</div>
Async.Pending = Pending
```

Pending is a function component and it's exposed as a static member of the Async class.

Now I have the following type definition for it (in typings/index.d.ts):

```
declare class Async<T> extends React.Component<Props<T>, State<T>> {}
declare namespace Async {
  export function Pending<T>(props: { children?: Children<T> }): React.ReactNode
}
export default Async
```

`Props<T>` and `State<T>` are interfaces. `Children<T>` is a type alias.

With this setup I keep hitting this error: "Type error: JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property."

I was able to make it work using the following:

```
type AsyncInterface<T> = React.ComponentClass<Props<T>, State<T>>
declare const Async: AsyncInterface<any>
export default Async
```

However I don't see a way to define Pending as a static member on that.

The full source code is here: https://github.com/ghengeveld/react-async

Comment: What code produces that error?

Comment: Have you tried this? `declare class Async<T> extends React.Component<Props<T>, State<T>> { static Pending: props: { children?: Children<T> }) => React.ReactNode } export default Async` ?

Comment: @Aaron I've set up a clean Create React App project with TypeScript. Using the Async component anywhere in the app JSX will trigger the error.